# Submit to URL on change

Tags: jquery

I need to replace links with drop-down selector. My links contain multiple variables:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="'.$showURL.'"'.($resultsBy == '' ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>option 1</option>
    <option value="'.$showURL.'showPercent&thold='.$threshold.'"'.($resultsBy == 'showPercent' ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>option 2</option>
</select>
```

I am using jQuery but struggle to finish my function:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
    window.location = ??? (this.value ?)   
});
```

Does not seem right to use this.value...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
    location.href = this.value;
});
```

Here is the way I would approach it.

JS

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
    location.href = this.value; // or $(this).val();
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option selected disabled>please select</option>
    <option value="http://google.com">google</option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want `$(this).val()`, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(function(){
  $("#mySelect").change(function(){
    location.href = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And I will stab with:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
    window.location = $(this).children('option:selected').val();   
});
```

personally I prefer:

```
$("#mySelect").on('change', function(){
    window.location = $(this).children('option:selected').val();   
});
```